# I want to change this code to put my dataset(from my drive it's an Arabic data with 2 classes) tried to read it normally but i get an error in 'train'

Tags: python, spacy

I want to change this code to put my own dataset(from my drive it's an Arabic data with 2 classes) tried to read it normally but i get an error in 'train' .. what i want is to use the dataset that i have not the ones from huggingface.

```py
!pip install openprompt
!git clone https://github.com/thunlp/OpenPrompt.git
!cd OpenPrompt
# load dataset
from datasets import load_dataset
# raw_dataset = load_dataset('super_glue', 'cb', cache_dir="../datasets/.cache/huggingface_datasets")
# raw_dataset['train'][0]
from datasets import load_from_disk
raw_dataset = load_from_disk("/home/hushengding/huggingface_datasets/saved_to_disk/super_glue.cb")
# Note that if you are running this scripts inside a GPU cluster, there are chances are you are not able to connect to huggingface website directly.
# In this case, we recommend you to run `raw_dataset = load_dataset(...)` on some machine that have internet connections.
# Then use `raw_dataset.save_to_disk(path)` method to save to local path.
# Thirdly upload the saved content into the machiine in cluster.
# Then use `load_from_disk` method to load the dataset.

from openprompt.data_utils import InputExample

dataset = {}
for split in ['train', 'validation', 'test']:
    dataset[split] = []
    for data in raw_dataset[split]:
        input_example = InputExample(text_a = data['premise'], text_b = data['hypothesis'], label=int(data['label']), guid=data['idx'])
        dataset[split].append(input_example)
print(dataset['train'][0])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The code you have pasted won't run (you seemed to have changed quotes to backticks?) and nobody can help you if you don't paste the error message.

Comment: okay @polm23 is it fixed now? the problem is i have been trying to change the path and i couldn't .. all i want is to put my data in this code .. plz if you have any idea i would be thankfull

Comment: You still didn't post the error message.

Comment: @polm23 here it is https://files.fm/f/phs38hqrd  but my problem is i don't know if i'm reading it right..

Answer (score 0):

The data should be in here:

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
raw_dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files='/content/drive/MyDrive/TEST2.csv')
```